# Work done by free expansion of gas and the energy of the piston

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation

So this has been bothering me for a while. I know that for a free expansion of a gas, work done by it is zero. However, I have a doubt regarding the kinetic energy gained by a piston during this free expansion of a gas.

So, let there be a cylindrical container of infinite length.
[image]

In the above picture, we can see that there is a fixed piston and a gas with pressure 'P', volume 'V' and temperature 'T'. The remaining volume of the cylinder is vacuum.

Now, the piston is released. As a result, free expansion of gas occurs and the piston moves towards the right.
[image]

Now, if the piston is massless, I can understand that no work is done by the gas as the kinetic energy of the piston is zero, due to mass being zero.

However, if the piston has a mass 'M', it will have a kinetic energy. However, if we again assume that work done by the gas is again zero, then where is the piston's kinetic energy coming from?

Also, in both cases, we are assuming that there is no gravity and that the movement of the piston in the cylinder is frictionless.

Comment: You show the case with the cylinder is open ended and infinitely long. How would your understanding change if a cylinder was a finite length and closed at the end?

Comment: @ChetMiller If the cylinder was finite, the expansion of the gas ends once the piston touches the end of the closed cylinder. At that point, the kinetic energies of the piston in both the cases will be zero. Also, after the expansion ends, the values of pressure, volume and temperature of the gas will change.

Comment: @ChetMiller Also, this process is irreversible. So, if it was an isothermal irreversible process, temperature of the gas remains the same, with new values of pressure and volume being $P_1$ and $V_1$. 
So, work done by the gas is: $W=P_1(V_1-V)$.

And, if it was an adiabatic irreversible process, the new values of pressure, volume and temperature are $P_2$, $V_2$ and $T_2$. Work done by gas: $W= -n*C_v(T_2-T)$.

And, by using:  $n*C_v(T_2-T) = -P_2(V_2-V)$.

Therefore, work done by gas:  $W= P_2(V_2-V)$

Comment: In the open cylinder case, the kinetic energy of the piston is not zero, and the piston keeps moving forever, and the gas keeps expanding forever.  In the case of the closed cylinder, in the final state, the piston will not be moving, and the combination of piston and gas will have done no work.  So $Q-W=\Delta U=0$ and $T_2=T_1$.  Also, no work will have been done by the gas on the piston.

Comment: @ChetMiller I’m confused. I understand that no work is done if the gas never stops expanding. But, why is no work done by the gas in the case of a closed finite cylinder, once the piston reaches the end? If we assume that the process was adiabatic, where no heat was given to the gas $(Q=0)$, the temperature of the gas after expansion should have decreased. As a result, there should be a decrease in the internal energy of the gas ($ΔU<0$), which means that the gas has done work. Therefore, work done by gas should be: $W = - ΔU$.

Comment: @ChetMiller 
And, in the case of an isothermal process, the heat is being given to the system $(Q)$ and since there is no change in internal energy of the system, due to the constant temperature, the heat should be used by the gas in doing work. Therefore, $W=Q$, where $ΔU=0$.

Comment: The combination of piston and gas does no work on the vacuum, right?  And, once the piston has come to a stop, its kinetic energy is zero; so, in the end, the gas has done no work on it.  So the gas has done no work, period.  And, since no heat has been transferred, Q = 0 too (adiabatic).  So Q = W = Delta U = 0.  Even if the piston collision with the far end of the cylinder is elastic, viscous stresses within the gas will eventually damp the piston motion, and the force that the gas exerts on the piston times the piston velocity will eventually integrate to zero.

Comment: @ChetMiller I don’t agree that for the adiabatic process, the temperature of the gas remains the same. Let us take a monoatomic gas $(γ=5/3)$ and let initial volume be $V=50 m^3$, pressure is $P=20Pa$ and temperature is $T=120.27K$ for 1 mol of gas. Now, after expansion, let the new volume be $V_1= 100m^3$. Therefore, using $PV^γ=P_1{V_1}^γ$ and $TV^{γ-1} = T_1{V_1}^{γ-1}$, we can then find values of $P_1=6.3Pa$ and $T_1=75.77K$. So, there is a drop in temperature, meaning that internal energy of gas decreases $(ΔU<0)$. So, where is that internal energy going, if no work was done by the gas?

Comment: That is for an adiabatic reversible process, not an adiabatic irreversible process.  Do you think that the ideal gas law equations apply to ideal gas behavior in an irreversible expansion?

Comment: @ChetMiller While the gas is still expanding irreversibly? No, it can’t be applied. But, it can be applied once the gas stops expanding (or has reached its new equilibrium position). So, we can apply the ideal gas law before the gas starts expanding and after it has finished expanding. So, in my above example, it is not possible to use the ideal gas law when volume of gas is $75m^3$, as the process is irreversible and the gas is still expanding. But, it can be used when the volume is $100m^3$, which is when the gas stops expanding and when the piston also stops moving.

Comment: The equations you used assume that the ideal gas law applies over the entire path not just at the ends

Comment: @ChetMiller Is there a way to prove that temperature remains the same in an irreversible adiabatic free expansion, without stating as fact that $W=0$, as my main contention is that W is not equal to zero? If it can be proved that temperature after the expansion is the same, then I will be able to understand that $W=0$, even for an irreversible adiabatic expansion.

Comment: I can show you how to prove that W = 0.  Would you accept that?

Answer (score 2):

If the piston has mass, then the volume change is not free expansion.  Free expansion has no resistance, nothing slowing it down.  The inertia of the massive piston does resist the expansion of the gas.  This is why the gas must do work on the piston in order to expand.  The only way to avoid this is to have an outside force keeping the piston in time with of the free expansion.  This outside force would then be the source of work on the piston.

Answer (score 0):

Force balance on piston:  $$F_g(t)=m\frac{dv}{dt}$$where $F_g(t)$ is the force in the positive direction exerted by the gas on the inside face of the piston, and v is the piston velocity.  Multiplying this equation by the piston velocity and integrating with respect to time gives:$$W_g(t)=\int_0^t{F_g(t)\frac{dx}{dt}dt}=m\frac{v^2(t)}{2}$$Since viscous damping forces from the gas cause the piston to eventually come to rest at the closed end of the cylinder (even with elastic collisions of the piston against the rigid closed end of the cylinder), the work done by the gas on the inside face of the piston is eventually equal to zero.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm if I understood this correctly. The viscous damping forces will act against the piston after the piston undergoes elastic collision with the wall of the container. After the piston has stopped moving against the gas, it will again move towards the wall of the container and strikes it, albeit with lesser velocity. This damped oscillation continues till the piston stops moving. And, as the gas did work in giving the piston kinetic energy, as well as work in stopping the piston due to these forces, the net work by the gas against the piston will be zero.

Comment: Excellent summary!

Answer (score -1):

If viscous force is ignored then also people say no work is done by a gas in free expansion. If piston is weightless, we can see that according to equation of colision , the piston will gain velocity but no momentum . According to me, force exerted by a gas on the piston largely depends on pistons weight . When it's weight is 0 force is also 0 therefore pressure exerted on it is also 0 that is why no work is done when there is massless or no piston. To inspect the case more closely , you can think of a moving particle (Classical particle) in massless box . Then think of 2 particles in the box with different velocity and see the motion of the box in both cases (if you plot graph of motion of the box then you will find a strange phenomenon)

Comment: If the piston is not weightless then work will definitely be done . We all know dW=F ds. Total work on the piston will be ( bF(in) - F(ex) )ds. Here F(ex)=0.